# Difference between 바랍니다 and 바라겠습니다

Tags: grammar, difference, word-choice

> 이번 추석 명절 잘 보내시길 **바랍니다**. (Literally) I hope you (will) spend this
>   Chuseok (Korean Thanksgiving day) well.

vs

> 이번 추석 명절 잘 보내시길 **바라겠습니다**. (Literally) Ditto.

Colloquially, the two sentences seem to mean the same, but is there any difference between the two? Which of the two sounds more grammatical?

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically all of those seems to be correct sentences.
But i would use 바랍니다 in this sentence because it sounds more polite and normal to me.
(Actually, even on television news, anchor uses 바랍니다 in this situation.)

In Korean dictionary, it defines -겠- as

> 완곡하게 말하는 태도를 나타내는 어미
>   End(ing) of a word that appears euphemistically speaking.

And we don't need this on this situation.

PS: 추석 already includes the meaning of 명절, so just use 추석 only.